# How to unfilter the project explorer in Eclipse IDE to show all kind of files

Tags: eclipse

I can't figure out how to show all types of files under the project explorer. I need to see some text files from the tree view but I'm able to see only .pl files. I have deselected all filters from "customize view...".

I'm able to open text files with the eclipse text internal editor from file->open file... but I can't see them in the project explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to refresh the project.
Select the project and hit F5.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to super user. If an answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Unfortunately not working, i mean by refreshing the Project its not listing all the files in the directory